# AngularJS ng-controller not working in v1.4.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please check my Code.

Why ng-controller not working?

```
<html data-ng-app="">
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS DEMO</title>
        <style>
            .container{
                padding: 5px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                margin: 2px 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
            <h3>Adding a Simply Controller</h3>
            Name : <input type="text" data-ng-model="textbox_emp" /> {{textbox_emp}}
            <br>
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="emp2 in emp_det">{{emp2.name}} - {{emp2.city}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div> 

        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
             function SimpleController($scope) {
                $scope.emp_det = [
                    {name: 'Chinu Sahu', city: 'Bhubaneswar', age: '25'},
                    {name: 'Sanjib Pradhan', city: 'Cuttack', age: '28'},
                    {name: 'Aruna Tripathy', city: 'Jajpur', age: '26'},
                    {name: 'Debasis Das', city: 'Balasore', age: '30'}
                ];
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

My `angular.min.js` version is : `v1.4.1`

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/ng/areq?p0=SimpleController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
I/<@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:6:416
Sb@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:21:401
Qa@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:21:1
We/this.$get</<@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:79:1
y@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:59:501
N@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:60:339
g@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:54:386
g@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:54:409
g@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:54:409
S/<@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:53:444
zc/d/</<@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:19:357
hf/this.$get</m.prototype.$eval@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:134:394
hf/this.$get</m.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:135:104
zc/d/<@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:19:315
e@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:39:17
zc/d@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:19:236
zc@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:20:30
Yd@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:18:342
@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:289:159
a@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:175:303
Gf/c@http://localhost/2015/test/AngularJS/AngularJS/js/angular.min.js:35:71


...r a=[];n(arguments,function(b){a.push(d(b))});return e.apply(b,a)}:function(a,b)...
```

Comment: Will you please share your js code ?\

Comment: I have shared my code. Please check above.

Comment: I am completely New. Today I am starting AngularJS.

Comment: @Chinu check the updated answer hope it help you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have any reason of omitting your module?

If you want to create controller , at first you need to create a module.

(you can't use global controller in angular 1.4)

You can create angularJS module like this:

```
angular.module('yourModuleName',[]);
```

and you create a controller on this module.

like this,

```
angular.module('yourModuleName').controller('yourControllerName',function($scope)
{ ... your controller logic});
```

I fixed your code based on this technique(above).

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular JS DEMO</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin: 2px 0px;
        }
    </style>
            <script src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
            angular.module('myApp',[]);
            angular.module('myApp').controller('SimpleController',SimpleController);
            function SimpleController($scope) {
            $scope.emp_det = [
                {name: 'Chinu Sahu', city: 'Bhubaneswar', age: '25'},
                {name: 'Sanjib Pradhan', city: 'Cuttack', age: '28'},
                {name: 'Aruna Tripathy', city: 'Jajpur', age: '26'},
                {name: 'Debasis Das', city: 'Balasore', age: '30'}
            ];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <h3>Adding a Simply Controller</h3>
        Name : <input type="text" data-ng-model="textbox_emp" /> {{textbox_emp}}
        <br>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="emp2 in emp_det">{{emp2.name}} - {{emp2.city}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</body>
```

I hope you understand it!

If you are new to angularJS, I recommend the book called "AngularJS Novice to Ninja".

Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks dear for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Global controller not valid for angular 1.3 or above

use modules:- `<html data-ng-app="my">`

```
angular.module('my',[]).controller('SimpleController',function($scope) {
});
```

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2qRTgHsFqs0dec8S79c?p=preview)

[Doc](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/docs/guide/migration)

Comment: Whoa, I didn't even know that there _was_ something like this kind of a global controller declaration!

Comment: I have used that code after googled. But that code also not working.

Comment: Again i am getting error after using your code - `ReferenceError: app is not defined
 

app.module('raddyx', []).contoller('SimpleController', function($scope) {`

Comment: @Chinu It's just a typo mistake, it's angular instead of app

Comment: Sorry that was typo I created the plunker hope it helps you :)

Comment: Yes I have changed angular instead app still getting error `angular is not difine`

Comment: you didn't add angualr.js  in html use cdn from http://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/

Comment: My changed code is `data-ng-app="raddyx"` in the html tag and `angular.module('raddyx', []).contoller('SimpleController', function($scope) {
                $scope.emp_det = [
                    {name: 'Chinu Sahu', city: 'Bhubaneswar', age: '25'},
                    {name: 'Sanjib Pradhan', city: 'Cuttack', age: '28'},
                    {name: 'Aruna Tripathy', city: 'Jajpur', age: '26'},
                    {name: 'Debasis Das', city: 'Balasore', age: '30'}
                ];
            });`

Comment: Add https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js in your header and read more here https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading

Comment: you missed "r" in controller  your code shows contoller